# How to use a radiobutton with IF statement?

Tags: wpf, if-statement, radio-button

I´m trying use **RadioButton** with statement **IF**

in short: I created a WPF application in which I want to select one of the four options and then click the button to open another window.I'd like to make sure the user clicked one off.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (here I don't know how to create a condition)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Musíš zvolit, jednu z početních operací!");
            }
            else
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

**RadioButton == unchecked** I thought of this condition but it does not go as well as the possibility of **or(||)**

as seen from the code I use error message in **if** and **else** opens another window

I'll be happy for any advice

Thank you

edit:
solution though not very nice

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (scitani.IsChecked.HasValue && scitani.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (odcitani.IsChecked.HasValue && odcitani.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (nasobeni.IsChecked.HasValue && nasobeni.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (deleni.IsChecked.HasValue && deleni.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Musíš zvolit, jednu z početních operací!");
                
            }
}
```

Comment: oh my. just write `if (scitani.IsChecked == true || odcitani.IsChecked == true || deleni.IsChecked == true || nasobeni.IsChecked == true) { new uroven().Show(); this.Close(); } else { ... }`

Comment: or just set one of radioButtons as checked by default `<RadioButton x:Name="scitani"  IsChecked="true"/>` and you won't need any validation because it is not possible to uncheck radiobutton without checking one of the others

Comment: @ASh with radiobuttons || it doesn't work but thank you for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reach your control

XAML:

```
  <RadioButton x:Name="myRadioButton"  />
```

CS:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myRadioButton.IsChecked.HasValue && myRadioButton.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Musíš zvolit, jednu z početních operací!");
            }
            else
            {
                uroven lvl = new uroven();
                lvl.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: IsThreeState="False" is default why I write it?

Comment: you don't need it.

Comment: great thanks to your help I figured it out. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I made a sample source for you by using MVVM pattern.

[Github](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/radio-button-group)

---

### Structure

[image]

---

### First,

you better use **ListBox**, that contains `RadioButton` as ListBoxItem.

#### `MainMenuViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class MainMenuViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private List<RadioItem> _radios;
    public List<RadioItem> Radios
    {
        get { return _radios; }
        set { _radios = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private RadioItem _currentRadio;
    public RadioItem CurrentRadio
    {
        get { return _currentRadio; }
        set { _currentRadio = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    ...
}
```

#### `MainMenuResource.xaml`

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="LBX">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource LBXI}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Radios}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding CurrentRadio}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

`Radios` binds to ItemsSource in ListBox, and `CurrnetRadio` binds to SelectedItem.

---

### Second,

by using **`Command`**, you can close the MainWindow and show the SubWindow.

#### `MainMenuViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class MainMenuViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

    public MainMenuViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand<Window>(Click);
        ...
    }

    private void Click(Window obj)
    {
        if (CurrentRadio.DisplayName == "Radio 1")
        {
            obj.DialogResult = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select another one!");
        }
    }
}
```

#### `MainMenuResource.xaml`

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BTN.MAIN">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    ...
</Style>
```

---

### Finally,

Because you need to control multiple windows in the application, it is common to treat them with the **OnStartup** method.

#### `App.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow main;
        SubWindow sub;

        this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        main = new MainWindow();
        main.ShowDialog();

        if (main.DialogResult == true)
        {
            sub = new SubWindow();
            sub.ShowDialog();
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's fantastic!!!how long have you been doing this?